# How to make "#include <ocilib.h>" and "using namespace ocilib" come true in Eclipse c++?

Tags: c++, oracle, eclipse, connection

I need to use database operation via Eclipse c++.
I looked similar questions here and discovered ocilib as answer. But using of it is complicating. I downloaded latest package, added path to include dir to my environment variable PATH, included this dir to my c++ project(Project - Properties - C/C++ General - Paths and symbols - Includes). Rebuilding project, but console still writing "ocilib.h No such file or directory".

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ocilib.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace ocilib;
```

Is somewhere exists instruction how really add include paths to Paths?

Comment: The environment variable `PATH` is used by the shell to search for *commands*. It's not used by compilers to find header files. And what is the path you have added to the project properties? What is the full and absolute path to the `ocilib.h` header file? Are you missing a subdirectory somewhere? On Unix-like systems (like Linux and macOS) you also have to rmember that all directory, path and file names are case-sensitive.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for reply!
I using os windows 10 x64. The path to ocilib.h is C:\dev\ocilib-4.7.3-windows\include\ocilib.h. So in Paths I includes "C:\dev\ocilib-4.7.3-windows\include" dir